# Bootstrap slider not being recognized even though the dependencies are there

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets, bootstrap-slider

Is there any reason why bootstrap slider is not being recognised as a function even though the correct dependencies are there?

The jquery ui files downloaded that are present in the web app folder are customised to not contain slider widget conflict functions.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script src="bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-slider.css">
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

<title>Bootstrap Slider</title>
<style>
</style>

<script>
    $("#ex1").bootstrapSlider({
        formatter: function(value) {
            return "Current value: " + value;
        }
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a jsfiddle or a screenshot of your console. If you say that you got all the dependencies (as I think your code is correct), I'm guessing you may have a problem with your paths.